# After reading from an fstream how do I set the curor back to pre-read position?

Tags: c++, parameters, fstream, seekg

I'm modifying a reading routine for **binary data**. Unfortunately I'm not that firm in C++ anymore, which is the language the routine is written in. The routine starts reading some data. After that I want it to **look at a buffered value** which I also read from the file. **Depending on the value** the code should either do something and continue normally afterwards **or *undo reading the buffer*** and continue normally.

My problem is the undoing or reverting the cursor position, if you will. The stripped code looks something like this:

```
int buffer;

std::fstream inputFile;
inputFile.open( "Filename", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary );

... // read some data from inputFile

// read buffer value
inputFile.read( reinterpret_cast<char *>(&buffer), sizeof(buffer) );

if( buffer == 256 ) {
    ... // do something here
} else
    // make it so nothing (including reading the buffer earlier) happened
    inputFile.seekg( -1*sizeof(buffer), std::ios::cur ); // <---- is this right?
    // or do I need to do it this way?
    inputFile.seekg( -1*sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(char), std::ios:cur );
}
```

I assume I can use negative values in `seekg()` as I find int only logicall and haven't read anything to the contrary. **Which way above is correct?** Or basically I'm asking **what does `seekg()` actually expect as first argument?**

The [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/?kw=seekg) only says this:

```
 istream& seekg (streamoff off, ios_base::seekdir way);
 off
    Offset value, relative to the way parameter.
    streamoff is an offset type (generally, a signed integral type).
 way
    Object of type ios_base::seekdir. It may take any of the following constant values:
    value   offset is relative to...
    ios_base::beg   beginning of the stream
    ios_base::cur   current position in the stream
    ios_base::end   end of the stream
```

Which doesn't tell me the unit `off` is measured in (bytes, chars, ints?).

Comment: Both look fine to me, `sizeof(char)` always equals 1, negative offsets are OK. The only bits that confuses me is `sizeof(buffer1)` vs `sizeof(buffer)`.

Comment: Remember the position you're at before you read with `tellg`.

Comment: Okay thanks. The variables `buffer` and `buffer1` where supposed to be identical. I just added a typo, which I just corrected. You have good eyes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of `seekg()` taking a `whence` argument takes an `std::streamoff` as argument. It can be negative. There is no need to divide by `sizeof(char)` as `sizeof(char)` is defined to be `1`. Since stream aleays operate on characters, the units used by streams are characters, i.e., the type of the first template argument of the stream.